# Overloading a function with otherwise identical signatures to accept both a reference and a const reference

Tags: c++, reference, constants, overloading

The codes are below :

```
struct A {};   

void f (A& a) {std::cout << "No const" << std::endl;} 

void f (const A& a) {std::cout << "const" << std::endl;} 

int main(){
   f(A()); // indicated as line A, output will be "const".
}
```

Question 1):

Why is line `A`'s output "const", even though `A()` is a non-const object ?

I reckon the compiler produces code equivalent to :

```
const A tempA;
f(tempA);
```

Is that right ?

Question 2), if the two f functions are modified as below, changing reference to value type

```
void f (A a) {std::cout << "No const" << std::endl;} 

void f (const A a) {std::cout << "const" << std::endl;}
```

These above codes are not able to be compiled. The compiler gives out "redefinition of function f" errors. I can understand why the error was given out by the compiler, because it is possible to convert `const A` to `A` and vice-versa. Thus there is no way to decide at compile-time. Is that right ?

I am still very curious that is it very well defined in c++ specification ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *Why the line A's output is "const", even though A() is a object without const?*

The `A()` expression creates a prvalue temporary that cannot be bound by a non-const lvalue reference, thus `void f (const A& a)` is the only viable overload.

> *I am still very curious that is it very well defined in c++ specification ?*

§13.1 [over.load]/p3:

> — Parameter declarations that differ only in the presence or absence of `const` and/or `volatile` are
>   equivalent. That is, the `const` and `volatile` type-specifiers for each parameter type are ignored when
>   determining which function is being declared, defined, or called. [ *Example*:
>
> ```
> typedef const int cInt;
> int f (int);
> int f (const int);           // redeclaration of f(int)
> int f (int) { /* ... */ }    // definition of f(int)
> int f (cInt) { /* ... */ }   // error: redefinition of f(int)
> ```
>
> — *end example* ]
>
> Only the `const` and `volatile` type-specifiers at the outermost level of the parameter type specification are ignored in this fashion; `const` and `volatile` type-specifiers buried within a parameter type specification are significant and can be used to distinguish overloaded function declarations. In particular, for any type `T`, “pointer to `T`,” “pointer to `const T`,” and “pointer to `volatile T`” are considered distinct parameter types, as are “reference to T,” “reference to `const T`,” and “reference to `volatile T`.”

For parameters of type `A` and `const A` the same conversion sequence applies when initialized by any argument convertible to `A`, the compiler would never be able to choose between the two.

For parameters of type `A&` and `const A&` there can be different expressions so that the compiler can choose a better conversion sequence or exclude any candidate from the set of candidates.

Answer (score 2):

In your first case :

`A()` creates a temporary, which is passed to your function. Temporaries can only bind to `const` lvalue references by specification. Thus, your `const` overload is chosen.

Note that a Visual C++ extension allows non-const lvalue references to bind to temporaries. This is non-standard, and is enabled by default, so beware. I do not know what overload would be chosen in that case.

In your second case :

The `const` qualifier of a function parameter qualifies the parameter itself, not the object that is its argument. Thus the only difference between your two functions is the `const`ness of your parameter *inside* the function.
In cases such as your first one, where the parameter is a pointer or a reference to a possibly const object, conversion and binding rules make a single overload viable (or preferable) for later function calls.
In that second case however, nothing qualifies your argument, so both overloads are undistinguishable by design (no later call can be unambiguous), hence the "multiple definitions" error.

Comment: Temporaries can bind to non-`const` references just fine. :P

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit standard-compliant proof or it didn't happen :p

Comment: Here's a complete program for you to test: `int main() { int&& x = 3; }`

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Oh, you nitpicking troll. There's not even a crumb of C++11 in this question for you to gnaw on.

Comment: @Quentin: I'm not "nitpicking": it's currently 2014, and therefore C++11 or C++14 are assumed. Your answer made a plainly fallacious statement in that context, whether the OP's code happens to also be valid legacy C++03 or not. It's deliberately ironic, I'm sure, that your profile says you're a "C++11 enthusiast". Apparently not so enthusiastic about it after all! :)

Comment: @Quentin You might want to read [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/112650/166623).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The part *before* "C++11 enthusiast" may hint at why it seems so. C++11 by default ? How I'd love to hear that from the mouth of teachers and managers ! The 10-years lag in the spreading of the new versions is getting on me. I apologize for the incomplete answer, and will care not to give into language fossilization !

Comment: @Quentin: I would love to hear it from them, too! Let's set a good example for them. :)

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a temporary object to pass to function here f(A()); The constructed object is only used in function. Temporaries are always const. This will work if you construct objects outside of the function call. Ex.

```
A nonConstA;
f(nonConstA); //Will print "No const"

const A constA;
f(constA); //Will print "const"
```

Comment: "Temporaries are always `const`" Not true. The rules for binding them to lvalue references require that the lvalue reference be a reference-to-`const`, but that doesn't mean the temporary itself is immutable (it's not). In particular, your theory would disallow `A&& ref = A();` and break the entire move semantics model.